# Using ftok for message queue

Tags: ipc

Referring the [tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html) on system V message queue.

It contains the following sample for `ftok`:

```
#include <sys/msg.h>

key = ftok("/home/beej/somefile", 'b');
msqid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

Why is it necessary for the file (/home/beej/somefile) to be readable by the process to generate the key for message queue ?

Also, is it easy for an attacker to just guess the key value for message queue (key's type is long) ?

Answer (score 1):

As of man page of [ftok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok), file should be accessible (not readable):

> The ftok() function uses the identity of the file named by the given pathname (which must refer to an existing, accessible file)

At least the process have to stat it. You can test it with totally unreadable file but in directory which you can access and the file which is word readable but in directory you can not access.
As per attacker question may be it will be easier for attacker if he knows file which is used and trying to guess `proj_id` which as per man page again: *Today proj_id is an int, but still only 8 bits are used*.